What is the purpose of this cable in a liquid cooling server?
I found this cable (marked in red) in a Dell liquid-cooling server (R760 Rack Server) but have no idea what it is. This cable is connected to the cold plate (indicated in the figure below), but I don't know the purpose of this cable. The cable is connected to a slot under the liquid pipe on the other end of the cable, as shown in the 2nd figure.
The cable goes under the riser. When I removed the riser, I found the interface to which the cable connected on its other end, as shown in the last figure.
Also, I tried to pull it out from its slot (highlighted by a red circle) and power it on, and the server and the fans can work properly. So, the purpose of this cable confuses me. Any ideas?




It’s probably the CPU fan. What’s the cable connected to other than that connector?

Have you checked the server's (or, ideally, mainboard's) manual yet?

Post a link to the English manual for the server

@Ramhound it should not be the CPU fan. The CPU is under the cold plate. It is a direct-to-chip cooling CPU. The fans are in the lower part of the photo. All fans work properly after I pulled it out from the white slot.

@Daniel and Ramhound I don't have a manual for it, but found a link here

@Enter - Sometimes there is also a Pump header that replaces the CPU fan header, easier, to just look at the manual. Look on page 36. In the end the port is documented in that manual.

@Ramhound thank you! Did you mean it corresponds to number 7, a jumper? Well, the position looks like incorrect. The connector should be on top of a cold plate, which covers a CPU. In the figure on P36, the connector is near PCH instead.

@Enter - I have no frame of reference. The header we’re talking is documented in those diagrams. What is the cable connected to on the other end of the cable. It’s clearly separate from the water loop.

@Ramhound thank you! Yes, the cable and the header (connector?) are separated from the water loop. The other end of the cable is connected to a slot under the liquid pipe (cannot be seen but indicated in the 2nd figure). Please see my update.

So the cable goes under the riser? Lift the riser. I have incomplete information

For sure that looks like a power cable connecting to the PSU which is inside the "Riser 4" compartment. And it connects to CPU 1. So it could be a power-switch-connection to remotely start up the Server when you don't have physical access to the power button.

@1NN thank you for the reply. The cable connects from a port on the cold plate of CPU1 (instead of CPU1 itself) to a port on the cold plate for CPU2 and finally connects to a port inside the Riser 4.

I can only bet it's temperature/humidity sensor that's built-in the plate. Can you share the link/data from the QR code in the first image? I cannot figure it out. By reading about that part, you'll probably encounter information about that port/cable. EDIT: btw cool demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7b3DZlSIyI

@Netan thank you very much for the information! I'm not sure if it is a sensor cable. I will share the QR code next time when I go to the lab. Do you mean that I could see information about that port/cable by scanning it?

@Ramhound anyway thank you! I will lift the riser next time when I go to the lab.

@Enter You might get a part number, then you can search for it's specs, connectors, etc.

@Ramhound, I lifted the riser today and found the other end of the cable. Please see my update. Thank you so much!

I'm guessing a sensor-cable as well, Purely based on the fact is runs to both cold-plates. But the server shouldn't boot, or at least give diagnostic errors on booting, while it is disconnected. Either the poster missed those during his testing or it really isn't important in which case I'm totally at a loss to explain the purpose of this cable. (To me a sensor whose presence/failure status can't be determined during diagnostic is weird. That means that during normal operation you can't tell if it is working properly or not either.)

The manual must indicate if this is some sort of cpu pump sensor or header. Screenshot quality doesn’t capture any text on the board to identify it though

So, using the latest ( third ) picture you've attached, combined with this article, it seems that board is a daughter-board for the rear IO. Did you lift "Riser 3"?
This article shows the port you looked at, on the second image (the top board out of the two). You can see the removable liquid-cooling holder (piece of plastic) in both your 3rd image, and that second in the article.
Now, I just had to find the SKU of that little "Rear IO board".
Two hours later, ta-da, step #3 - "DLC leak detection cable"!!!


I have edited your post to focus and clarify it, and removed unprofessional language.

@Netan When I see your reply I have no time to read it (including the links) before I can award the bounty to you!! Thank you!

@Enter Sure man! It was an interesting question :)

@Netan may I know what is "SKU" in "...had to find the SKU of..." :-)

@Enter haha sure, it's like an identifier for a product. might be a barcode or a random number each product within a company get. There must not be any duplicate values. Example for SKU here, just under the name of the product: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/ibuypower-y40-black-gaming-desktop-pc-intel-core-i7-14700f-nvidia-geforce-rtx-4070-12gb-32gb-ddr5-ram-2tb-nvme-black/6576689.p?skuId=6576689

Also, an explaination from Google: “stock keeping unit” - is a number (usually eight alphanumeric digits) that retailers assign to products to keep track of stock levels internally. If a product has different colors and sizes, each variation has a unique SKU number.
